# $GL({\mathbb C})$ as an Algebraic Group

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

An affine algebraic group is an affine variety $G$ such that multiplication and the inverse map are polynomial maps. However, $GL({\mathbb C})$ is given as an example of an algebraic group. Since the formula for inverse of a matrix involves rational functions I do not see how $GL({\mathbb C})$ is well-defined as an algebraic group!

Comment: The map given by the inverse is required to be rational, not polynomial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ does not embed as a Zariski-closed subset into $\mathbb{A}^{n^2}$, but into $\mathbb{A}^{n^2+1}$. A matrix $A \in \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ is identified with the vector $(A,\det(A)^{-1})$. You can convince yourself, that the inverse map is a polynomial if we regard $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ as that subset of $\mathbb{A}^{n^2+1}$.

Also note that affine varieties are not required to be embedded in an affine space. Hence, morphisms between affine varieties may not be polynomials in an obvious way.

Comment: Could you spell out why $GL_n({\mathbb C})$ does not embed into ${\mathbb A}^{n^2}$. Thanks!

Comment: @Hansgluckmann It does embed, but as an open set rather than as a closed one, which is what we really want.

Comment: So to spell it out even more, the polynomial function det picks out the open set of all matrices with zero determinant and $GL({\mathbb C})$ is the complement to this, i.e. a closed set. Is this correct?

Comment: @Hansgluckmann No, that would be an open set (the way it embeds in $n^2$-dimensional affine space as an open subset). The coordinate algebra for $GL_n$ is polynomials in $n^2+1$ variables where you mod out by $t\cdot det - 1$ where $t$ is the last variable and $det$ is the determinant polynonimal.

Comment: @Hansgluckmann It's exactly the opposite. $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ is a (principal) open subset of $\mathbb{A}^{n^2}$.

Comment: . . . .  sorry, I have mixed up open and closed it seems!