# Showing $GL_n(k)$ is Zariski open and a bijective correspondence.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Show $\text{GL}_n(k)$ for some field $k$ is Zariski open in $\Bbb{A}^{n^2}$. For this I noticed the complement of $\text{GL}_n(k)$ is the zero set of the determinant which is a closed subset, so $\text{GL}_n(k)$ must be open? Am I correct here?

Then I'm asked to show that there is a bijection between $\text{GL}_n(k)$ and a closed subset of $\mathbb {A}^{n^2+1}$.

Now I noticed one space dimension $n^2$ but the second has dimension $n^2+1$. So I thought of a map $\text{GL}_n(k) \to \Bbb{A}^{n^2+1}$ via
$$(a,b,c,d) \mapsto (a,b,c,d,ad-bc)$$

Does this work? And is my first part correct?

[image]

Comment: No, there is no bijection between $GL_n(k)$ and $\Bbb A^{n^2+1}$, but just an embedding - see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1943472/gl-mathbb-c-as-an-algebraic-group) for example.

Comment: I took the liberty of fixing some of the formatting, but I'm puzzled about this question. Do you really care about _bijections_? As opposed to isomorphisms of varieties, or birational maps? Also, it's not true that one space has $n^2$ _elements_ and the other has $n^2 + 1$ _elements, right? Was this is typo - did you mean "dimension"?

Comment: The dimension of $GL_n(k)$ as a (quasi-affine) variety.

Comment: @DietrichBurde my homework problem says to find a bijection correspondence between the 2 and i wanna say hilberts theorem of zeros applies or?

Comment: @KennyWong see the photo ive attached!

Comment: @anonymous Your homework question is different from what you typed! You're meant to show that $GL_n(k)$ is in bijection with a **closed subset** of $\mathbb A^{n^2 + 1}$.

Comment: AHHHH @KennyWong youre right@

Comment: @KennyWong i wrote that in the question though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with your solution to the first part.

For the second part, you might like to apply the [Rabinowitsch trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabinowitsch_trick). The Rabinowitsch trick says that if $f$ is a polynomial in $k[x_1, \dots, x_m]$ and $g$ is the polynomial in $k[x_1, \dots, x_{m+1}]$ defined by $ g(x_1, \dots, x_{m+1}) := x_{m+1}f(x_1, \dots, x_m) - 1$,
then there exists an isomorphism between the open variety $\mathbb A^m \setminus V(f)$ and the closed variety $V(g) \subset \mathbb A^{m+1}$. This isomorphism is the map $(x_1, \dots, x_m) \mapsto (x_1, \dots, x_m, 1/(f_1, \dots, x_m))$.

To apply the Rabinowitsch trick to your problem, take $m = n^2$ and take $f$ to be the determinant function.

Finally, I would remark that the wording in your homework question is a little odd. We're doing algebraic geometry, not set theory. So it's strange to be asked to prove that there exists a *bijection* from one variety to the other. It would feel more natural to prove that the two varieties are *isomorphic*, i.e. there exists a bijective *morphism* from one variety to the other, whose inverse is also a morphism of varieties.